# Put and direct setting sobject value does not show

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, field-update

I am trying to set a custom field of an custom object from apex

```
object.put('field__c','value');
object.field__c = 'value';
```

Both of these lines do not set the value. However is I log the result of put it does show the old value of 'field__c'. Any suggestions as to where to look for a solution ?

Comment: If this is a custom field it should have the suffix `__c`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In the actual code the field has the __c suffix this was just to illustrate the code. ( I will add it here as well)

Comment: Could you show the full code with System.debug please ? Maybe something else is wrong

Comment: Where is this code? A before trigger, after trigger, controller? Are you doing an insert/update after it?

Comment: The code is in a controller. Adding an update call solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have found out what the problem was.
The object variable was created from a query. 
After setting the field calling

```
update object;
```

saves the value to the field

Answer (score 1):

The `put()` method on SObject will set the new value, but return the previous value of the field.

> Sets the value for the specified field and returns the previous value
>   for the field. [Apex Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put)

So if you put a log on the result of `put()` it would return the previous value.

```
MyObject__c.MyField__c = 'Hello';
System.debug(MyObject__c.put('MyField__c', 'World'); // Returns 'Hello'
System.debug(MyObject__c.MyField__c); // Returns 'World'
```

Comment: This does work but after that when I go to the page of the object the field is still on the old value